# [Teams][botbuilder] Empty lines in Adaptive Cards TextBlock

Tags: node.js, botframework, whitespace, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We need empty lines in Adaptive Cards TextBlock.

I was able to do it in https://adaptivecards.io/designer/ with `\n&nbsp;\n\n`
But when I send it from my bot service, MS Teams is displaying `&nbsp;` in text.

Do you know if there any workaround to do it in **botbuilder js** ?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: it will work, as a workaround/the last option.. but I don't really like it. still looking for something within single TextBlock

Comment: Would you let me why you want to have a single text block so that I can try to solve the actual problem you're having? Would a rich text block be acceptable or does it have to be a regular text block?

Comment: RichText is not acceptable it is much more harder to parse and seems links like we can do with markdown will not work, so separate text blocks is the answer I have accepted. Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting separate paragraphs in separate text blocks